# How to calculate probability for infinitely countable sets

Tags: probability, self-study

Suppose that my sample space is $\mathbb{N}.$ My experiment is choosing an $x \in \mathbb{N}.$ Every $x$ is also equally likely.

What's the probability of choosing 1?

Comment: There does not exist any such probability distribution, because "equally likely" and "countably infinite" imply the probability of any $x$ is zero, but then the total probability would also be zero, which is impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've the answer in the comments, but let me elaborate on it. Total of all probabilities should be $1$, and since it's countably infinite, we need to be able to sum the probabilities for totalling out.

If all equally likely, we have $\mathbb P(X=i)=c$, and $$\sum_{i=0}^\infty \mathbb P(X=i)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty c = 1$$

and no real $c$ satisfies this equality, which means the distribution is undefined.

Comment: Thanks. This makes perfect sense to me, but a colleague argued that, c could be some epsilon, as the width of the uniform distribution approaches infinity.

Comment: Still, that wouldn't define the distribution well. We can't say it's $0$, and we can't specify the value of the epsilon.